# Typical firing patterns of neurons in the default mode network in resting state

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuron

Inspired by the Wikipedia article on the [default mode network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_mode_network#History) where I read:

> Hans Berger, the inventor of the electroencephalogram, was the first
>   to propose the idea that the brain is constantly busy. In a series of
>   papers published in 1929 he showed that the electrical oscillations
>   detected by his device do not cease even when the subject is at rest.

I came up with the following question:

> Are there data available for typical firing patterns of single neurons
>   (of a given type, in a given region or functional unit) in the
>   [default mode network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_mode_network) in [resting state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resting_state_fMRI)  over some significant
>   period of time, say a minute?

By "typical firing pattern" I mean:

- the overall number of spikes (per minute)
- the number of isolated spikes
- the number and duration of tonic bursts
- the number and duration of other firing patterns as [proposed e.g. by Eugene Izhikevich](https://www.izhikevich.org/publications/whichmod.pdf)
- and the mean distances between them

Or are such data not available, maybe because they are too hard to gather or cannot be summarized in a sensible way.

I ask just to get an idea, and because I would like to know if - for example - the maximal, mean, or median number of spikes per minute has an order of magnitude of 10, 100, 1,000 or 10,000 - or even more?

Comment: The DMN is composed of many different cortical brain areas each containing many cell types; I think it would be difficult to define anything as 'typical' among them. There are also no hard borders to the DMN; you could define some for a given purpose, but it would be hard to find agreement.

Comment: Both classifying neurons into proper subtypes and recording firing patterns of neurons (in their natural environment) are not very easy tasks. [This review](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrn.2017.85) (not sure if freely available) is mostly about the classification but also contains a good introduction & some examples on different electro-physiology.

Comment: @Nicolai, thanks for the link, unfortunately not freely available. (What to do?)